# C program palindrome game

Tags: c

I'm new in c programming and i'm trying to make a palindrome game. I've given the code below but there is some mistake I'm making  and doesn't run can you please give me a hand. Thank you.

The point of the game is to give number to an array, then change with the keys a,d,x,w and try to make it palindrome.

If there is any error can u please give me some advice ?

This is ***pal.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "visible.h"

//--------------------------------------------------
// is_pal
//--------------------------------------------------
void print_status(int a[], int* p, int num_mov);


int is_pal(int a[])
{
    int b[6];
    int i, j;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        b[j] = a[i];
        j++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


//--------------------------------------------------
// process_movement
//--------------------------------------------------

void process_movement(int a[], int* p, int num_mov, char c)
{
    char d;
    d=c;
if(d == 'd') 
{

    p = a+1;
    num_mov++;
    print_status(a,p,num_mov);
}
else if(d == 'a')
{
    p = a-1;
    num_mov++;
    print_status(a,p,num_mov);
}
else if(d == 'x')
{
    p = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    a = p-1;
    num_mov++;
}
else if(d == 'w')
{
    p = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    a = p+1;
    num_mov++;
}
}
//--------------------------------------------------
// print_status
//--------------------------------------------------

void print_status(int a[], int* p, int num_mov)
 {
  printf("Number =  ");
  int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
 printf("\n Number moves = ");
 printf("%d", num_mov);
 //printf("\n ","%s%", "Pointer is at position ");
 printf("%d", *p);
 printf("\n");
}
void user_game_palindrome(int pal_num)
{

    int a[5];
    int i,num_mov;
    num_mov = 0;
    i = 5;
while (pal_num != 0) {
    a[i] = pal_num % 10;
    pal_num = pal_num / 10;
    i--;
}
    int *p = a;
    while (is_pal(a) == 1)
    {
        char c;        
        print_status(a,p,num_mov);
        c = ask_for_command();
        process_movement(a,p,num_mov,c);
}
}
```

This is ***ex1.c***

```
#include "pal.h"

int main() {
    int pal_num = 123342;

    user_game_palindrome(pal_num);

    return 0;
}
```

***visible.c***

```
#include "visible.h"
#include "conio.h"
//--------------------------------------------------
// gen_num
//--------------------------------------------------

int gen_num(int lb, int ub) {
    int num = (rand() % (ub - lb)) + lb;

    return num;
}
/* Note: Do not forget to include the following instruction at the beginning of your main() method:
srand(time(NULL));
*/

//--------------------------------------------------
// my_getchar
//--------------------------------------------------

char my_get_char() {
    char my_char;
    int b = 0;
    char dummy_char;

    my_char = getchar();

    while (b == 0) {
        dummy_char = getchar();
        if (dummy_char == '\n')
            b = 1;
    }

    return my_char;
}
```

this is  the visible.c ( my teacher told me to include it)

Comment: Check loops in `is_pal`. You are accessing out-of-range `a[6]` and the condition `i>=6` should be wrong.

Comment: Check second for loop in is_pal, you should check if (a[i] != b[i]) return 0, and after the for loop is finished you should return 1, because you've checked that there is no error. And the condition in the second for loop should be i < 6, because you want the loop to run as long as i < 6, not as long as i >=6.

Comment: thank you very much, I did change it and tried to run it but it still doesn't run.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that in the process_movement function you've got d == 'x' twice and you're missing a d == 'w' statement. In user_game_palindrome you should be checking while (is_pal(a) == 0). you're playing as long as is_pal(a) returns 0, because when it returns a 1 it means you're done.

Comment: Thank you i changed it again still no luck :(

Comment: Does it return incorrect answers, show incorrect values, or not run at all? (Also, what is visible.h and do you need it?) Post some errors because finding your problem at this moment has become a guessing game of its own.

Comment: When i run it i get Debug Error, Run-time Check failure #2 - S

P.S i added the visible.c file

Comment: @PavelVasilev I posted an answer so it would be easier to read. Please check if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your conversion from `int` to `array` is wrong

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    a[i] = pal_num%10;
    pal_num = pal_num % 10;
}
```

Here, why would this loop end when `i` is `4`. It should go till `pal_num` is `0`. And `pal_num = pal_num % 10;` should be `pal_num = pal_num / 10;`

Try something like

```
i = 0;
while (pal_num != 0) {
    a[i] = pal_num % 10;
    pal_num = pal_num / 10;
    i++;
}
```

**NOTE:** Be aware, that this would essentially reverse your `int` and store in the `array`.

Comment: I see, it should be 6 my fault(there will be only 6 numbers in the array). I did change pal_num = pal_num/10 but it still doesn't work

Comment: if i change i = 6 and i--; it wouldn't reverse the integer right ?

Comment: i = 5. remember that the array is numbered 0, 1, ..., 5

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot going wrong in your code and you still haven't fixed many things which have been pointed out by others.

as to remove the unnecessary creating of the array b, is_pal can be defined as:

```
int is_pal(int a[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (a[5-i] != a[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

process_movement doesn't have a case where **d == 'w'**

user_game_palindrome should have the while loop checking (is_pal(a) == 0)

And you should apply the changes that were suggested by @Haris

Comment: Thank you i did and it's not giving that run time error anymore.

Comment: Although I have a few other problems now

Comment: If your current state is the same as the code posted, then perhaps its because of the **int a[5];** where it should be **int a[6];** for a 6-element array (in your user_game_palindrome function).